# How to call a function exposed via defineExpose when that component is rendered multiple times inside a v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 component that exposes a function via defineExpose.

```
<template>
    ....
</template>
  
<script setup>
...

defineComponent({
  name: "SomeComponent"
});

function doStuff() {
  ... does stuff
} 

defineExpose({
  doStuff
});
</script>
```

That component is used in another component inside a v-for

```
<template>
  <div
    v-for="(item) in lst"
    ref="someComponentRefs"
  >
    <SomeComponent :attr="item" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const lst = ref([1, 2, 3]);
const someComponentRefs = ref<Array<typeof SomeComponent>>([]);

function doStuffToItemOnIndex(index: number) => {
    const target = someComponentRefs.value[index];
    target.doStuff() // This won't work since target is a DOM node
}
</script>
```

According to [this doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) I need to add the `ref` attribute to the div that has the v-for. I can then use it to get the ref. What I want however is to pick a specific ref from the array and call the `doStuff` function on it. The way I do it now does not work since `const target = someComponentRefs.value[index]` returns a DOM node instead of a Ref.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ref` refers to the element that it is attached to. So you need to place it as the attribute of your component like so:

```html
<div v-for="(item) in lst" >
    <SomeComponent ref="someComponentRefs" :attr="item" />
</div>
```

Comment: yesm this works. Hmm, this is different from the docs, but perhaps I just didn't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @KoenPeters Did you understand the solution? I can elaborate more if you have any concerns.

Comment: Jep, I did some more reading and I get it now. Thanks!